# Resetting or deleting sessions/variables created in a require_once file?

Tags: php, require-once

If I create a php file and use `require_once` to include a php file in my project ([paypalplatform.php](https://github.com/iamezell/spotaplace-public/blob/master/php/paypalplatform.php)).  I then use one of the functions from paypalplatform.php in my own php file.

How do I remove paypalplatform.php from my own php file so all the sessions/variables etc set within paypalplatform.php are reset fully so I can use payypalplatform.php again later in my php file to call a different function from paypalplatform.php?

So basically the following works

```
--start of php file--
<?php
    require_once("paypalplatform.php");
    myarray = function_one_from_paypalplatform();
?>
--end of php file--
```

The following also works

```
--start of php file--
<?php
    require_once("paypalplatform.php");
    myarray = function_two_from_paypalplatform();
?>
--end of php file--
```

However, the following does not work:

```
--start of php file--
<?php
    require_once("paypalplatform.php");
    myarray = function_one_from_paypalplatform();
    unset(myarray);
    myarray = function_two_from_paypalplatform();
?>
--end of php file--
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you'r using OOphp...

You have the file "something.php".

In something.php you have:

```
require_once('someelse.php');
```

On someelse.php you have:

```
public $var1 = 'test';
public $var2 = 'abc';
```

So, you have a index.php and use like that:

```
$obj = new something.php;
echo $obj->var1; //test
$obj->var1 = 'lol';
echo $obj->var1; //lol
unset($obj);
$obj = new something.php;
echo $obj->var1;//test
```

or use your include as a var.

```
$varinclude = require_once('something.php');
```

use as you wish, and when needs to reset, just include or something the phpfile on other var or rewrite the same.

Comment: So the following will work? `$varinclude = require_once('something.php');` then reset it using `$varinclude = "";`, then include it again using `$varinclude = require_once('something.php');` ?

Comment: @Guerra 

`$varinclude = require_once('something.php');`

require function returns the result of including, i.e. `false` or `1`

Comment: I get the same problem with `$varinclude = require_once('something.php');` then reset it using `$varinclude = "";`, then include it again using `$varinclude = require_once('something.php');` ?

Comment: No, sorry man. zogby got the point. this just i'll return a bool saing if its load or no. You should use "new Class" as OOPhp to figure it as you wish.

Answer (score -1):

Unset your session variables and variables. When you include a file, it becomes a part of a file into which you have included it.
The code above is not actually PHP though.

Comment: So I have to unset each and every session variable and variable created by paypalplatform.php in the file which require_once's the paypalplatform.php file?  Only reason I ask is because paypalplatform.php file has a lot of code so I am assuming it will have a lot of variables and sessions.  I was hoping for a quick and easy way to unset everything in paypalplatform.php.  Is that not possible?

Comment: Once you've included a file, its functions become visible to your scope. There is no actual need to worry about the access to those functions.

Comment: Fair enough.  However, I still need to reset all the sessions and variables created by that file included without resetting the sessions and variables of the file which the included file was included in.  How do I go about doing that without checking the included files sessions and variables and resetting each and everyone one by one?

Comment: You can do it using namespaces.